# Changing a 24volts module device to 12 volts supply?

Tags: voltage

I have a 24 volts requirement to power a relay module device. I want to install it in car but the car has available 12 volts from the main battery. Temporarily, i have added a device to step up the 12 volts supply to 24 volts in order to run my relay device.

Is there a way to change the 24 volts supply requirement of the module device into 12 volts?

Hope to receive a reply. Thanks

Comment: Is the solenoid accessible? If so, you could replace it with 12V coil version, if it is a standard form and you can match the contacts. You might add some details about the module to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You mention relay module, and this is designed to run from 24 volts. Relays contain a solenoid, which creates a magnetic field to activate the switch element of the module. The solenoid is a coil of wire.  It will have a certain amount of electrical resistance because of the length of the wire (could be hundreds of ohms). In order to modify the relay module to work off 12V instead of 24, you will need to reduce the coil resistance, which means unwinding the coil and cutting out a lot of the wire (reduce its total length by half).  It's often difficult to unwind these coils.

Now, unfortunately, you may find the side effect of reducing the length of the wire is that the magnetic field produced by it is also reduced, and the mag field may not be strong enough to operate the switch contacts. You can try it, but test it thoroughly after you reduce the length of the wire in the coil to ensure that it can reliably activate the switch contacts.

You may find this practically difficult to shorten the length of the wire to reduce the resistance.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to change the 24 volts supply requirement of the module
>   device into 12 volts?

My first thought is "what does the data sheet tell you?". If there are no clear answers in the data sheet, you could contact the supplier or manufacturer. If no recommendations from them then you are faced with the only options being: -

- Use a step-up boosting regulator
- Add another 12V battery to make 24V locally for the device
- Get a different device that is 12 volt compatible.

---

EDIT regarding rewinding the relay: -

The force exerted by the relay's electromagnet is a function of amps x turns. If you halve the number of turns you approximately halve the resistance and your new magnetization force at 12 volts is "same current" x half turns i.e. you have halved the force to activate to solenoid that closes the contacts. It's the "same current" because you've approximately halved the resistance by stripping off half the turns and of course half-volts / half-resistance = "same current".

The only way this idea works is by stripping off all the wire, folding the wire in half and winding two coils together. The wire "fold" becomes the new "supply terminal". You now have a new coil (two coils in parallel) that has the same total number of turns as the original but, is one-quarter the resistance therefore it would run from 6 volts rather than 12 volts.

Alternatively you could strip all the old wire off and rewind half the number of turns with slightly thicker wire (half the resistance per metre) and run at 12 volts with twice the current.

Comment: Let me contact the manufacturer to get a direct answer from them. Those 3 options were used temporarily. Thanks Andy.